# How to add controller endpoints to Razor Server in ASP.NET Core 7.0 / VS2022

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, asp.net-core-7.0

I am trying to add a controller with routing to a Razor server-side app. I tried several things but I only see solutions for .NET 6 and cannot figure it out.

I created a controller like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace SAAR.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("settings/[controller]")]
    public class ConfigurationController : ControllerBase
    {
        public ConfigurationController()
        {
        }

        [HttpGet("test")]
        public string Test()
        {
            return "Test a controller in Razor";
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my `program.cs` I added:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers();
```

and

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

AFAIK this should work and the endpoint `http://localhost:5000/settings/test` should be there but I get a http 404 error.

What am I doing wrong?

Here my complete `program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SAAR.Areas.Identity;
using SAAR.Data;
using SAAR.Services;
using SAAR.Settings;
using System.Configuration;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

// Add MVC Controllers
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.Run();
```

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Try using `http://localhost:5000/settings/configuration/test` - you have the `[Controller]` part in your "base" URL for the controller - so that'll show up in your URL, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, figured it out, thanx!

Just create a new Razor Server project and add a folder 'Controllers' and add a C# class:ConfigurationController.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace SAAR.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ConfigurationController : ControllerBase
    {
        public ConfigurationController()
        {
        }

        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public string Test()
        {
            // Route: /Configuration/Test
            return "Test a controller in Razor";
        }
    }
}
```

In program.cs add this code and remove duplicate app.[Method] calls.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

});
```

Insert this in program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllers();
```

So the complete program.cs looks like:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SAAR.Areas.Identity;
using SAAR.Data;
using SAAR.Services;
using SAAR.Settings;
using System.Configuration;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

// Add MVC Controllers
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

});
app.Run();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case,the uri should be `http://localhost:5000/settings/Configuration`

The name of your  controller is Configuration not test

```
[ApiController]
[Route("settings/[controller]")]
public class ConfigurationController : ControllerBase
{
 .....
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use routing / MVC-controllers in an Razor Server web app.

Comment: This is not correct. You can mix and match Razor Pages and MVC/API controllers in the same application.